# Rails - erratic Timeout errors possibly tied to asset compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, bower

> Preemptive apologies for the code dump. I've been banging my head against this one for a while (and doing a ton of Googling) and just have a pretty fuzzy idea what is and isn't relevant, and how to fix things. So I figured I'd get as much info as possible out there. **Please let me know if there's anything else I should add that might be helpful**. Thanks!

I'm starting up a Rails and Angular app and mostly still in development mode. I'm using Heroku, but I don't know if these issues are serious there as well, cause I've mostly been coding and bumping into them on local (have barely poked around on production). (Just mentioned, because most similar questions seem to be Heroku-specific).

The error I keep intermittently bumping into is this one:

```
 Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutError: Request ran for longer than 5 seconds.
```

and its doppelganger:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error: Request ran for longer than 5 seconds.
```

When it's raised, it points to different files as the immediate culprit -- but always a Java/CoffeeScript or CSS/SASS file. Occasionally reloading the browser on the local server will pinwheel eternally instead of raising the above error. Often, a refresh will work fine, but occasionally I have to restart the server to "unfreeze" it.

> I could try increasing the Rack::Timeout to something larger, but it strikes me that that would be treating one of potentially many symptoms, rather than the underlying problem.

I'm convinced this has something to do with an asset precompilation mistake of some sort -- which I'm new to, as this is my first serious app from scratch, particularly combining Angular and Rails.

> I've had a hard time finding really smooth combinations of Rails and Angular -- advice is definitely appreciated.

I've managed to pinpoint the error by running and rerunning some feature specs while messing with my manifest SASS file. Every time I change the `application.sass` file by commenting some `@import`s out, (some of) the feature specs fail, but if I re-run them, they pass again and again, until I comment in or out a different line. The specific line(s) don't seem relevant, but, just in case I'm wrong, here's my `application.sass` file:

```
@charset "utf-8"

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"

@import "bourbon"
@import "base/grid-settings"
@import "neat"
@import "base/base"

@import "leaflet"

@import "skeleton/base"
@import "skeleton/layout"
@import "skeleton/skeleton"

@import "sections/header"
@import "sections/footer"
@import "sections/user"
@import "sections/map"
@import "sections/tabs"

@import "sections/baseapp"

@import "markercluster/MarkerCluster"
@import "markercluster/MarkerCluster.Default"

@import "icons"

@import "font-awesome-sprockets"
@import "font-awesome"
```

Because I think my messy asset solution is possibly to blame, I'll paste most of the relevant code below. Basically, I'm using **NPM** (`package.json`) for server-side JS stuff like Jasmine for testing, and **Bower** for client-side stuff like Angular and Leaflet (for maps). To make the Bower JS available in the Rails app, I'm using **[Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/)** in my `Gemfile`. (Though I don't get why I need the `bower.json` stuff if I'm doing that). So the relevant parts of those manifest files look like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "whatever",
  "dependencies": {
    "rosie": "0.2.0",    
    "bower": "1.2.8",
    "jasmine": "2.1.1",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.13",
    "sinon": "1.12.2",
    "jasmine-sinon": "0.4.0",
    "requirejs": "2.1.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.4"
  }
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "whatever",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "authors": [
    "Whatever"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_compnents",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-resource": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest",
    "angular-mocks": "latest",
    "active-support": "latest",
    "async": "latest",
    "lodash": "latest",
    "leaflet": "latest",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "latest"
  }
}
```

> I mean to tie down the versions before putting this in front of users.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails-assets-angular'
gem 'rails-assets-angular-resource'
gem 'rails-assets-angular-route'
gem 'rails-assets-angular-mocks'
gem 'rails-assets-active-support'
gem 'rails-assets-async'
gem 'rails-assets-lodash'
gem 'rails-assets-leaflet'
gem 'rails-assets-requirejs'
gem 'rails-assets-sinon'
# gem 'rails-assets-leaflet.markercluster' -- wasn't working, so I included the relevant scripts in app/assets/javascripts/ -- seems to be working
```

I've also added these in the `test` group of my Gemfile. I'm worried about the overlap and sprawl of these JS inclusions, but this was what got the JS tests to work.

```
  gem "jasmine-rails"
  gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit'
  gem 'guard-jasmine'
  gem 'rails-assets-rosie'
  gem "sinon-rails"
```

I have a handful of assets I manually precompile for a variety of reasons:

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ 
  'api/bookmarklets/view.js', 
  'sections/bookmarklet.css',   
  'icons.eot',
  'icons.svg',
  'icons.ttf',
  'icons.woff'
]
```

Locally, (and on production for now), my assets are just hosted on the server (so at `localhost:3000`). Doubt the DB is related, but its pool is set to `2` and timeout to `5000`. Searching for other possibly related code, I found this in `config/environments/development.rb` -- possible problem?:

```
  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
```

**EDIT** -- adding a full stack trace from one of the errors I hit while running the feature specs:

```
# /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:125:in `[]'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:125:in `process_comment'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:88:in `s'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `block in stylesheet'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:545:in `block_contents'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:123:in `asset_digest_path'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:76:in `compute_asset_path'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:132:in `asset_path'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `asset_path'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:256:in `stylesheet_path'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:100:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:96:in `map'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:96:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
 # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__3935206380113339538_2226830520'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:79:in `block in profile_method'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in `render_with_layout'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `new'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionview-4.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:79:in `block in profile_method'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/airbrake-4.1.0/lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/request_store-1.1.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/airbrake-4.1.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/airbrake-4.1.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-timeout-0.1.1/lib/rack/timeout.rb:104:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:193:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:60:in `process'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:38:in `block in process_and_follow_redirects'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:37:in `times'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:37:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:42:in `visit'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/authentication_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:5:in `run_background_jobs_immediately'
 # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/zeus-0.15.2/lib/zeus/rails.rb:208:in `test'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/zeus-0.15.2/lib/zeus.rb:148:in `block in command'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/zeus-0.15.2/lib/zeus.rb:135:in `fork'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/zeus-0.15.2/lib/zeus.rb:135:in `command'
 # /Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/zeus-0.15.2/lib/zeus.rb:50:in `go'
```

**Updates**

Following coreyward's advice, I set the Rack timeout to 25 seconds and set up some profiling tools. The increase in the timeout (which was dev-environment specific) made the problem go away on localhost. But, perplexingly, *I didn't seem to experience any load times of 5+ seconds at all*, according to NewRelic and MiniProfiler. I think the longest load time I got was around 3 seconds, and I only got that once. I improved a query, and didn't bump into load times that high again. So it's weird that I bumped into that 5-second limit.

Basically, the load time problem seemed to disappear when I increased the Rack timeout. But I there's still something weird going on, cause the feature tests will still time out in Continuous Integration tests and occasionally on local .

I since cleaned up my asset situation (got rid of Bower and NPM, and did everything through the Gemfile, usually using the Rails-Assets gem). I also upgraded to Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2 for performance enhancements. Things generally appear to load a bit faster, according to profiling.

But I'm still getting the same test failures. Interestingly, on my Continuous Integration tool, the tests pretty much always fail, and when they do, they fail with a different error (I captured with a screenshot).

```
Internal Server Error

could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)

________________________________

WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-12-25) at 127.0.0.1:47539
```

This suggests it's a DB issue. My DB set up (`database.yml`) for the Test environment (which my CI uses) is below:

```
  adapter: postgresql
  database: planit_development
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 2
  timeout: 5000
```

But, weirdly, my local test suite, which has the same settings, tends to pass (unless I mess with an asset file, in which case there's a chance a feature spec will fail on the first, but not subsequent, run(s)). And *the tests that are failing are the least database-intensive tests in the whole suite (just basic auth flow testing)*.

The profiling definitely helped me fix some mistakes, but I'm still pretty stumped here about what's the root cause of what appears to be a continuing problem. Any ideas based on this new info? Or any sense of what else I should look into?

Comment: try increasing timeout `Rack::Timeout.timeout = 10`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm worried that this would mask, rather than solve the problem -- why is it taking so long to load pages to begin with? (Added a similar thought above).

Comment: I know this will not be directly helpful, but from my experience, using Angular inside the Rails environment will always cause issues, and it's definitely not the Angular way of doing things. 

The Angular app should be developed and deployed independently of Rails opinionated, asset pipeline, fine tuned for multi page applications rendered by rails on the back end just like good ol 1999 asp.net pages ... 

Then rails should only be used as a JSON API service.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to debug this. To start, increase the Rack::Timeout time to 25 seconds — while this might seem like it's going to make matters worse, it will allow you to accurately assess the actual time the request is taking (5.1s is a different story than 25s).

Instrument a monitoring tool like NewRelic or Skylight. The former is more popular and can be easily configured to log traces on all requests over a certain threshold. This will allow you to see (roughly) where the time is being spent, as well as parameters/request information that relates to it.

If you think that the requests that are failing are to assets, I would double check that you have asset compilation turned off in production. You want this in `production.rb`:

```
# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false
```

This means that you need to make *every* asset you're serving precompile. You can test that your setup is correct by running `rake assets:precompile` and verifying that the output in `public/assets` is what you're anticipating.

Make sure you're also outputting logs somewhere you can access them later — I prefer Papertrail, but there are undoubtedly others. This will allow you to find errors when they occur, especially 404s (which is what you'll see if you have requests for assets that are not precompiled). Once you isolate and resolve the issue you can lower this, but I still wouldn't set it lower than 15s.

Garbage collection is another potential culprit for intermittently long request times, though 5 seconds is probably excessive. Newer versions of Ruby (notably, 2.2) are better about managing this, so if you can bump the version you're using that might improve things.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, coreyward. I tried your suggestions , and made some improvements to load times, but am still bumping into these problems. Put an update above. Any ideas what else I should look into?

Comment: @Sasha After reading your updates it sounds an awful lot like you're running into issues with either your DB connection pool, the DB connection limit your local db server is configured with. I think the timeouts you were experiencing in production are due to having a single-threaded webserver. If Rack::Timeout starts timing while another request is being handled, your response time doesn't need to be > than the timeout ceiling.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I 100% understand what you're suggesting, though. Increase the DB pool? Any suggested number? I'm running Unicorn both locally and on production. And when you say "If Rack::Timeout starts timing while another request is being handled, your response time doesn't need to be > than the timeout ceiling", does that mean that switching to a multi-threaded server would solve the problem? I'm loath to switch servers, because Unicorn is what Heroku recommends.

Comment: Your DB pool should be about the same as the number of connections  your database supports, but you'll have to do the math to figure out what that means per instance. If you have a worker and 4 processes on Unicorn, you'll want to divide your total allowance by 5 to get the right number of connections per instance. // Your log above specifies WEBrick, but that might just be in your integration tests… not sure. Unicorn is okay, though I really prefer Puma. They both work well enough on Heroku, though Puma is going to keep your memory footprint (and thusly, costs) down.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure I got to the bottom of this particular problem, but you definitely helped me improve the app performance in a number of ways. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sasha - While the answer is helpful, I don't think it really provides a solution since it didn't solve your problem. The upvote seems appropriate, but I don't think the check mark does. I am also having the same problem as you, and I was expecting that the check mark indicated this was the solution. Other people are less inclined to answer if they see the problem is marked as solved.

Comment: That seems fair. Would also love an answer to the underlying problem, so I'll uncheck it.